# Convert JSON LINES file to JSON format?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonlines

I have file (around 6 GB) that each line is JSON.

```
{"name":"name1", "age":40, "car":null}
{"name":"name2", "age":30, "car":null}
{"name":"name3", "age":30, "car":null}
```

How can I convert it into a JSON array with Python?

Comment: create a list, then iterate over each line of your file and append it to your list, finally export the list as json

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You need to enclose the file's contents in `[` and `]` brackets and add a comma between each line — there's no need to read the entire thing into memory at once to this.

Comment: `jq -s . in.json > out.json`?? why python?

Comment: Thanks @eroot163pi!! That works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=True):
    if 1 != fileinput.filelineno():
        print(',{}'.format(line), end='')
    else:
        print('[{}'.format(line), end='')
open("test.txt","a").write(']')
```

Answer (score 0):

Load each line and save it into a list.

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = [json.loads(line) for line in in_file.readlines()]
```

Then you can save that to a file like with `json.dump()`

```py
with open('out.json', 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump(lines, out_file)
```

Comment: No need to use `readlines()`: `for line in in_file:` would work just as well and use half as much memory.

Comment: Actually you don't even need to do that — just do `json.dump(list(in_file), outfile)`.